# LINQ query to update same collection?

Tags: c#

I have a collection List1 in which there r 5 items.
based on some condition i want to remove some items from List1 but 
do not want another collection for updated item.
i want that updated collection will be in List1.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, to extent it does not really matter for *this question* - it is not possible to update the same collection using LINQ methods (one that take `IEnumerable<T>` as argument).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a `List` you can use [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method:

```
List1.RemoveAll(_condition_);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

nameList.RemoveAll(x => x.FirstName == "Bob");

Comment: +1 to both "RemoveAll" answers, also strictly speaking it is not LINQ query.